# Spring Boot with Google App Engine and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using **Spring Boot with Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL, using MySQL.**. Locally it's working fine, but after deploying to Google App Engine, the site is not loading. I checked Google's Error Reporting and I saw this exception.

Please suggest how to resolve this.

In my **application.properties**

```
 spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/<<DB_NAME>>?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=<<Instance connection name>>
    spring.datasource.username=<<username>>
    spring.datasource.password=<<pwd>>
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
    spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

**Exception:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:680)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:642)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:612)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:806)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
>     ... 36 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC
>   Connection for DDL execution  at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:69)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:329)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
>     ... 43 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server.   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2492)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:818)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:307)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
>     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534)
>     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)    at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43)
>     ... 55 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain
>   credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:549)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:140)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:300)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2416)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
>     ... 76 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Application Default
>   Credentials failed to create the Google App Engine service account
>   credentials class
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.
>   Check that the component 'google-api-client-appengine' is deployed.
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getAppEngineCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:315)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:119)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:91)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:547)
>     ... 81 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApplicationClassLoader.findClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:45)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:265)   at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.forName(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:161)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getAppEngineCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:300)
>     ... 86 more

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or is your own code? Also, did you enable [the Cloud SQL API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/)?

Comment: It's my own code(Ref from Google). Yes, I Enable the Cloud SQL.

Comment: In this case, a good approach would be following a tutorial, and after this tutorial is working, add your own code, piece by piece. A example close to your situation would be [this one](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql), as it uses Spring Boot, App Engine Flexible and Cloud Sql.

Answer (score 0):

The way you connect to Cloud SQL locally is different from the way you connect to it from App Engine. Namely the JDBC URL is different. From App Engine it has this format: `jdbc:google:mysql://[connection name]/[db]`.

If you are using the [Cloud SQL starter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-starters/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql), this is automatically configured for you.